# How to make wind force stop affecting objects not in range?

Tags: animation, particles, cloth-simulation

Wind force affects everything in the scene when its not even near it. Is there a way to make it only affect things close to it. Other than turning wind force off in field weights, effector collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you can influence it by the "min distance" in falloff here:

[image]